# why the following error when I try to run the code in the real device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am a newbie to IOS programming. I build a very simple xcode program. Connect my ipad to the mac book, then click
production-> run, I received the following error

> Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
>
> No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

I would like to know why and how to solve it?

Comment: So it looks like you don't have a developer license, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be any reason for this. 
1. Your device is not registered.
2. This is because device is not connected. Firstly connect device [image: It will display device as iPhone 5]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: my device's OS is too high for Xcode, after updating, I can connect now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have registered to one of the Apple Developer programs, you can register your device and create a provision profile.

Its a process, not simple for newbies.

Comment: it is simple, all you need is to follow the step to end with two files certificate and developer profile. Later on install them on your Mab Book.